# How to downgrade Visual Studio 2017 update 15.9 to 15.5 without uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have updated Visual Studio 2017 a few months back and the current version of visual studio 2017 is 15.9. But today, It shows that trial license has expired.

I have a license key for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 but it is acceptable with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.

So, I would like to downgrade my Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 to 15.5. Please suggest how I can do this without uninstalling the whole Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the license trial period is affected by a minor change in VS version number. What kind of edition do you have? Community is free.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Major version licenses are good for all minor releases. If you have a license for 15.5, it will work fine with version 15.9. Downgrading will not start your trial period over. If you can't afford to buy Visual Studio, the Community version is free.

Comment: @Steve I have Visual Studio 2017 Professional version 15.5 license key. Any solution, if uninstallation is not a good approach?

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to say that your key is "not acceptable with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9"... Clearly, a key isn't the issue there. Visual Studio trials are 30 days, not "a few months". So if you successfully ran 15.9 for a few months and now you have a licensing issue, it's obviously not because a 30-day trial expired.

The Visual Studio license definitely is unaffected by such patches within a version number. If your key works with 15.5 it will work for 15.x.

Go to your VS **Help | Register Product** menu and see if you can re-enter your product key there. If not, what does it say?

In general, if you think you have a valid license key and in actuality you do not, you will need to contact Microsoft for a resolution.